# Cargar contenido en un Fragment

Tags: android, android-fragment, android-imageview

La aplicación se carga de forma correcta pero pasa por alto una modificación en el código.
Trato de cambiar una imagen cargada desde un recurso pero no surte efecto alguno al ejecutarse.

Instancio una View donde cargo la vista del Fragment y su contenido, instancio el widget que quiero cambiar (**ImageView**) y lo modifico como se muestra acontinuacion pero al ejecutar el espacio asignado queda en blanco.

```
 @Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // Inflate the layout for this fragment
    // Inflate the layout for this fragment
    View root_view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_pet_tab, container, false);
    pet_slider_layout = root_view.findViewById(R.id.slider_layout_pet);
    RequestOptions requestOptions = new RequestOptions();
    requestOptions.centerCrop();

    TextSliderView textSliderView = new TextSliderView(getActivity().getBaseContext());
    textSliderView.description("hanibal").setRequestOption(requestOptions).image(R.drawable.pet_not_found_es);
    pet_slider_layout.addSlider(textSliderView);
    return view_root;
}
```

[image: espacio en blanco donde se debería cargar el recurso gráfico]

**EDIT:**

Imagen del actual error al cargar
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Solo debes retornar la instancia del `View` de tu Fragmento de esta forma: `return root_view;`, ya que como lo tienes actualmente solo estar inflando tu diseño.

Comment: Así funciona, el problema lo tengo en otro fragmento, que al modificar queda cargando un bucle

Comment: Adjunto una imagen de lo que ocurre

Comment: Te falta un parámetro `false` en tu `inflate()` deberia de ser `inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_pet_tab, container,false);`

Comment: Mucha gracias, ahi funciona correctamente, resulta graciosos que así lo tenia desde un comienzo, luego modifique y ahora regresé y funciona. Gracias nuevamente